# How to use replace to update the column items

Tags: mysql, select, replace, sql-update

I'd like to change the ',' char into '.' at one of my column . I can make the replace syntax but it just a view. And i want to update it for the all records!

```
select cast(replace(egysegar,',','.')as decimal (10,3)) from temporary
```

i'll tried the next one to update

```
UPDATE temporary set egysegar = replace(egysegar,',','.') where egysegar is not null
```

but after i get an error :

> you are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you're using MySQL Workbench and you actually have to disable the safe mode or add in the `WHERE` clause a key column, exactly as it says in the message.

Or you can run `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` before your update query.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer is that MySql run with safe-updates option. It mean you can't update or delete record without key primary key on where clause.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

or use primary key in where clause